# How to debug "Error parsing XML: mismatched tag"?

Tags: java, android, xml

I already closed the tags but it still gives me error, when I compile it says:

> Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

And in the XML Copy Editor it says this to me when saving "Premature end of data in tag PreferenceScreen line 2", please somebody could write me the code like I should put it ?, the truth I do not know what I do wrong, I am a beginner.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
         </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
             <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />
        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
        <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" >
              <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Next time ask in English or go to Spanish version https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: English only please

Comment: Conversation should be in english only. So that we can help you and get back to you with desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgot to close the "**com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference**" tag at two places.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />

        <!-- start <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference> -->

        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />

        <!-- close your </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference> here -->

        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />

        <!-- start <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference> -->

        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
             <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />

         <!-- close your </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference> here -->

        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
        <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" >
              <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference` tag with the `intent` inside is not closed. E.g.

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
        <!--
          Close the com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference here !
        -->
    </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```